Error in Java is not visible in Visual Studio Code
I'm using Visual Studio Code for study, and I'm encountering an issue where I can't see the errors in my code. Normally, errors are indicated by red lines around the problematic areas, but in my case, there are no red lines appearing.
I've made sure that the "Java Extension Pack" extension is installed in my Visual Studio Code, but I'm still experiencing this issue. i already tried searching on google and searching on stackoverflow about the same problem I experienced but i only find the problem was on c and c++ and i already tried enable the error squiggles too but it didnt have the impact on the java error. and i already tried clearing workspace cache but the result is still the same. How to fix it
ussualy there is error shown
The error was shown in terminal after i run the code
The error was shown
